# Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect

Tags: java, android

I know there are already such questions but I couldn't find any answer that could help me.

I am trying to get a Google Maps API key for which I have to have a MD5 key using this command :

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "/Users/Sachin Parashar/.android/debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

but it is giving this error :

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:792)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 7 more
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this command?

Comment: *Password verification failed* : wrong password ?

Comment: Running as Admin didn't help.

Comment: I've been Looking of answer for a couple of days , i found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-n5wR-p3u0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Read the stacktrace. This error is raised when your password is just wrong.

As you're dealing with the `debug` keystore, you can remove it and create a new one.

First, delete this file

```
/Users/Sachin Parashar/.android/debug.keystore
```

Then, run (on the same folder, i.e. `/Users/Sachin Parashar/.android/`)

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Finally, you can run what you were trying before

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "/Users/Sachin Parashar/.android/debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: Where did I enter any password here?

Comment: At this part of the command: `-keypass android`. You have passed `android` as password for the keystore. But that is not the correct password

Comment: How do I know what is the password?

Comment: @2Dee  It's just that I never set any such password and had no idea what password it is asking for.