# Generate Signed Apk - Keystore was tampered error

Tags: android, apk

When I export signed apk in Android Studio, I have an error about Cannot load key store: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

So I am writing true password but I have an error. I read a lot of topic about this but I can't find solution.  I'm sure that I have true password.

I must update my app in play market.

What can i do ?

Comment: "I read a lot of topic about this but I can't find solution." What exactly did you try and what happened when you did?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

Comment: this is say : delete keystore and create new. but i don't want this. i try to run a lot of code on cmd and terminal

Comment: `or try following command which will create a new xyzkeystore:...`

Comment: yes. I tried this.

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: I don't want to create new key. Because I want to update my app on store

Comment: most likely you are not typing the correct password

Answer (score 0):

I had these keystore issues when I was working before. And as far as I know the best solution for this is just create a new keystore.

[Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511430/keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

Comment: No this is about tomcat